# Why is exception handling often looked down upon in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

I have seen the trend that many people don't like to use exceptions in their c++ programs.

Some people even go as far as saying that exceptions are not natural to c++.

Game programmers generally disable exception handling  .

Also Exceptions handling is usually avoided in performance critical applications.

I do know that c++ didn't always have exception handling.

Are there good reasons to avoid it?

Comment: How _isn't_ it off topic? It assumes facts not in evidence (exception handling being "generally looked down upon in C++"). The only thing this will do is debate things, and this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: The only thing wrong is the slightly presumptive tone of the question (which you could edit). Exceptions might not be _generally_ looked down upon but they are _often_ looked down upon. The reasons why (aka answers) are enlightening and educational.

Comment: @xeon111: I edited the question to try to 'fix the tone'. Please revert if you disagree.

Comment: @sje397 I do agree with the changes. I was out of ideas how to complete the body ,so i wrote something that kinda  made the question sound a bit open-ended (personal opinionish). I Would still like to see this question to be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have four problems with exceptions:

1. People are tempted to use them as part of non-exceptional program flow
2. In order to use them properly, you also need to be well versed in other C++ techniques (RAII, smart pointers)
3. It offers an 'easy way out' - "stuff it - I'll just throw"
4. Without careful planning, you often you end up with a large number of 'catch' statements on the outer level of the program (or worse, 'catch-all')

So I tend to not use them in a team with programmers of widely varying skills. They're great when used properly though.

Answer (score 4):

There are good reasons to avoid exceptions:

1. exception safety is slightly difficult and requires following conventions very carefully
2. in gaming there just isn't that much stuff that can fail on runtime. Everything that can fail is pretty much in initialization of the game; loading of files etc, which is not in core performance part of the game. If it's in performance critical section of game, should ask why it can fail in the first place?
3. stack unwinding causes problems with debugging the software. When something throws, it's difficult to find where in the code it did happen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why people would just not use exceptions in C++ but as for performance critical code I can see why. Usually it is relatively expensive to incur an exception versus the C-style handling of returning an error code and delegating some error handling for that. My guess is that this is legacy C++ code from before exceptions were implemented. Another reason could be that it just doesn't make sense to write exception classes and such when it's much easier to handle errors in another way. The 2nd statement I cannot really comment on as it seems to opinionated to provide a good answer for (might stem from the fact that C++ didn't always have exceptions).